# Why is the probability different when you do in different ways?

Tags: probability

Let's say you have four marbles in a bag, 3 red and 1 blue. If you randomly pick two, there is a 50% chance that the blue one is in your hand, but if you pick one at a time, there is a 25% chance probability that the first one is blue and a 33% chance that the second one is blue if the blue one is not in your hand. If you add these, they are not 50%. Can someone explain what I did wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps it's easier to see if we label the marbles $\color{red}{R_1},\color{red}{R_2},\color{red}{R_3},\color{blue}{B}$.

Of the four, you can pick them up in $\binom 4 2$ different pairs:

- $\color{red}{R_1},\color{red}{R_2}$
- $\color{red}{R_1},\color{red}{R_3}$
- $\color{red}{R_1},\color{blue}{B}$
- $\color{red}{R_2},\color{red}{R_3}$
- $\color{red}{R_2},\color{blue}{B}$
- $\color{red}{R_3},\color{blue}{B}$

Three of these have the blue marble, hence $50\%$.

---

If you pick them up one at a time, assuming without replacement, then you can have these sequences:

- $\color{red}{R_1} \to \color{red}{R_2}$
- $\color{red}{R_1} \to \color{red}{R_3}$
- $\color{red}{R_1} \to \color{blue}{B}$
- $\color{red}{R_2} \to \color{red}{R_1}$
- $\color{red}{R_2} \to \color{red}{R_3}$
- $\color{red}{R_2} \to \color{blue}{B}$
- $\color{red}{R_3} \to \color{red}{R_1}$
- $\color{red}{R_3} \to \color{red}{R_2}$
- $\color{red}{R_3} \to \color{blue}{B}$
- $\color{blue}{B} \to \color{red}{R_1}$
- $\color{blue}{B} \to \color{red}{R_2}$
- $\color{blue}{B} \to \color{red}{R_3}$

In each case, the first marble has a probability of $25\%$ to be picked up, and the second $33.\overline{3}\%$. Hence, twelve possibilities in all.

Notice the difference here: order is important to consider here, unlike the previous one. Notice further, that of these, precisely six contain the blue marble - so, again, $50\%$ is the answer.

---

A particular error arises in your calculation here:

> there is a 25% chance probability that the first one is blue and a 33% chance that the second one is blue if the blue one is not in your hand. If you add these, they are not 50%.

These probabilities are **not** independent of each other or disjoint, so you can't blindly add them.

The probability the first is blue is $25\%$, yes. That's the probability for having it on the first grab. However, what of the second grab? A second grab to get the blue marble is necessary $75\%$ of the time, and of those times $33\%$ will have the blue marble. So really the answer in this framing is

$$\frac 1 4 + \frac 3 4 \cdot \frac 1 3 = \frac 1 2$$

as intended.

Answer (score 4):

The probability that the second one is blue is dependent on the outcome of the first draw.  If the first draw is blue, there is 0% chance that the second one is blue.  There is a 3/4 chance the first one is not blue, followed by a 1/3 chance that the second one is blue.  (3/4)(1/3) = 1/4.   Add that to the 1/4 chance the first one is blue and you have 1/2.